# Prestashop 1.7 how to add or edit product condition?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop 1.7. I would like to **add** a condition other than **new**, **refurbished** and **used**. Or I want to **edit** these condition names. How can I do it?
[image: Screenshot of product conditions list in product editing page]

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking question: *What have you tried so far with code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"*

Comment: I've added a screenshot for your help. I hope that will be useful. Thank you for your warning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't change any of it or add a new. Because it is hardcoded in the core files and even has validation in the Poduct.php file(main products' class). But you can try just change translation for these fields through Improve -> International -> Translations it can help you to change the names for front-end

Comment: Good idea. But I can't find the terms on the translations menu. I guess translation from the administration panel is also not allowed.

Comment: I guess you can change it only for front-end but not for admin part, so it can be a little confusing

Comment: My problem solved. So I changed "Used" word with "Second Hand" word. I make changes in this file: /www/app/Resources/translations/en-US/ShopThemeCatalog.en-US.xlf